# Allow a user to create another user which belongs to him/her?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I have an Institute model using devise. I want to allow an Institute to create another devise model, Users. I want the created user to belong to the institute that created it by adding an institute ID to the User model.

But, for that I think I'll have to override the default registrations controller for just the User model. If I do that, that'll override it for the Institutes model too (not sure about this), which I don't want.

To be clear, I don't want to use roles in just one user model.
I want the institute model to be separate. My user model will have separate roles (a teacher and a student), which the institute can set while creating.

How do I do it?

Comment: do you sign in as an Institute or as a User?

Comment: @bosskovic You sign in as an institute.The institute adds a user and then the users can also sign in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institute
end

class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In your user creation form, you add a hidden field `institute_id` that corresponds to the currently signed in institute.

If you also want to allow the users to register, then you add a select whose keys are institute ids and values institute names.

You can also reuse the same form partial by conditionally rendering the hidden field or the select.

Comment: Actually, the user cannot add other users. The ability to add users belongs only to the institute. and I get the model relations where I am stuck is, how do I update the institute ID of the user as the institute creates it?

Comment: ok, got it, you have 2 devise models. Can there be a User that belongs to no Institute? Also can a User belong to multiple Institutes?

Comment: No. Every user has to belong to an institute.

Comment: please take a look at the edited answer and tell me if that works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. The hidden field idea didn't strike me at all (Y)